# My native iOS application font size and images are scaling up on larger screens :(

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

My native iOS applications font size and images are scaling up for iPhone 6 + and iPhone 6. I want them to be same for all the screen sizes like in Skype and Instagram iOS application (don't want the font and images to get scaled). Please help.

Comment: Are they scaling automatically?

Comment: Use Size Classes..U can solve very easily

Comment: @Uday.M - he says he doesn't want it.

Comment: Exactly. I doesn't want fonts and images to get scaled up. And yes they are scaling automatically. I want the application font and images to be consistent for all the screen sizes like in Skype and Instagram iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all for your all Elements it will not change the size. 
It just change your the position according the device Size.

In Size Inspector

[image: Auto Resizing]